# Use virtualenv owned by root in a python web project on production

Tags: python, django, nginx, virtualenv, uwsgi

So I have the following configuration:

- Nginx server with uWsgi
- Django project in a virtualenv

My virtualenv is owned by an ordinal system user and the whole configuration works fine!
The uwsgi process is configured to run with nginx uid & gid, as well as the nginx process owner in the nginx.conf.

But, if I try to use another virtualenv satisfying the same requirements, but owned by root, my uwsgi can't locate the virtualenv, throwing an import error.

Is this normal and is my aproach correct to use a root owned virtualenv?

**Edit:**

- uwsgi config:

  ```
  [uwsgi]
  virtualenv = /root/Envs/rootenv
  thread = 4
  uid = nginx
  gid = nginx
  env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myServer.settings
  module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()
  chdir = /var/www/myServer
  socket = /var/run/uwsgi/myserver.sock
  logto = /var/log/uwsgi/myserver.log
  ```
- /root/.bashrc:

  ```
  ### Virtualenv settings ###
  export WORKON_HOME=/root/Envs
  source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
  export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME
  export PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV=true
  ```
- uwsgi log traceback:

  ```
  *** Starting uWSGI 1.9.15 (64bit) on [Fri Sep  6 14:02:41 2013] ***
  compiled with version: 4.7.2 on 06 September 2013 10:59:26
  os: Linux-3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.41-2+deb7u2
  nodename: myserver3
  machine: x86_64
  clock source: unix
  pcre jit disabled
  detected number of CPU cores: 2
  current working directory: /
  detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
  setgid() to 32
  set additional group 4 (adm)
  setuid() to 32
  *** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
  your processes number limit is 7929
  your memory page size is 4096 bytes
  detected max file descriptor number: 1024
  lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
  uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /var/run/uwsgi/myserver.sock fd 3
  Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 14:09:21)  [GCC 4.7.2]
  Set PythonHome to /root/Envs/rootenv
  ImportError: No module named site
  *** Starting uWSGI 1.9.15 (64bit) on [Fri Sep  6 14:03:13 2013] ***
  compiled with version: 4.7.2 on 06 September 2013 10:59:26
  os: Linux-3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.41-2+deb7u2
  nodename: myserver3
  machine: x86_64
  clock source: unix
  pcre jit disabled
  detected number of CPU cores: 2
  current working directory: /
  detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
  setgid() to 32
  set additional group 4 (adm)
  setuid() to 32
  *** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
  your processes number limit is 7929
  your memory page size is 4096 bytes
  detected max file descriptor number: 1024
  lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
  uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /var/run/uwsgi/myserver.sock fd 3
  Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 14:09:21)  [GCC 4.7.2]
  Set PythonHome to /root/Envs/rootenv
  ImportError: No module named site
  ```

Comment: Could you add the import error, the full traceback and the uwsgi configuration?

Comment: I'have edited and added the traceback